# How to design an HTML table inside a PHP tag?

Tags: php, html

I have got the following code from virtuemart ([Joomla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joomla) extension) component. The script was under a particular function and is used to show "product type" information from the database. If you go through with the code below you will see the code is querying the database and then displaying data as a table. When I run the script, the table looks very plain and simple. I want to have the table look something like the table in the image I have posted below.

I have tried to add some CSS for the table in the very page where I got the code from, but when I open the page its layout gets changed and look ugly. So I have to add or make any change I have to do in the following code.

I don't have good knowledge on PHP and CSS. What are some necessary changes/additions to make for the following table to look like the table in the image I have posted below?

```
    $html .= "<br />\n<table width=\"100%\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" border=\"1\">\n";
    $html .= "<tr><td colspan=\"2\"><strong>".$VM_LANG->_('PHPSHOP_PRODUCT_TYPE_PARAMETERS_IN_CATEGORY').   ": ".$dbag->f("product_type_name")."</strong></td></tr>\n";

    // SELECT parameter value of product
    $q2  = "SELECT * FROM #__{vm}_product_type_".$dbag->f("product_type_id");
    $q2 .= " WHERE product_id='$product_id'";
    $dbp->query($q2);

    // SELECT parameter of Product Type
    $dba->query($q.$dbag->f("product_type_id")." ORDER BY parameter_list_order");
    $i = 0;
    while ($dba->next_record()) {
        if ($i++ % 2) {
            $bgcolor='row0';
        }
        else {
            $bgcolor='row1';
        }
        $html .= "<tr class=\"$bgcolor\" height=\"18\">\n";
        $html .= "<td width=\"30%\">".$dba->f("parameter_label");
        $parameter_description = $dba->f("parameter_description");
        if (!empty($parameter_description)) {
            $html .= "&nbsp;";
            $html .= vmToolTip($parameter_description, $VM_LANG->_('PHPSHOP_PRODUCT_TYPE_PARAMETER_FORM_DESCRIPTION'));
        }
        $html .= "</td>\n<td>";
        $html .= $dbp->f($dba->f("parameter_name"))." ".$dba->f("parameter_unit")."</td></tr>\n";
    }
    $html .= "</table>\n";
}
return $html;
```

The Table Image

[image]

Comment: You REALLY don't want to do this.  This was how PHP scripts were written in the bad old days and the result was code that was unmaintainable and design that was unchangable.  There's been years of effort since to keep the layer that does the work as separate from the layer that presents the output as possible.

Comment: Additionally, your code is wide open to SQL injection.  DON'T BUILD SQL QUERIES WITH STRING CONCATENATION!  http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm really recommend you to learn PHP and HTML. Check out this webpage to learn PHP, HTML, and CSS: http://www.w3schools.com/

In your example, `$html .= "blabla"` means add `blabla` to the variable `$html`. This PHP script makes a table that should be perfect when it comes to the HTML. You have to change the CSS. Here you can change the colors and the style and the text fonts size and so on. With the information you have given until now I really can't help you.

So I recommend you learning CSS, letting the source code you get when you run the webpage and make the table yourself. Because CSS doesn't take long to learn, and it takes even less time to learn how to edit an already-existing CSS document.

Have a look here for CSS: http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Have a look here for tables in CSS: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

Comment: @50ndr33 Your comments are also inappropriate. Please remember to treat other community members with the same respect you'd like to receive. A downvote is not a reason to call someone a child and/or an idiot.

Answer (score -2):

You should go through the [W3Schools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools) tutorial *[CSS Tables](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp)* for styling table with CSS.

Comment: Nobody should ever go through a W3Fools tutorial on anything.